# setFillWidth doesn't work in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

I have this code:

```
public class Minesweeper extends Application {

private MenuBar menuBar;
private Stage primaryStage;
private final VBox vbox = new VBox(8);
private GridPane gridpane;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage=primaryStage;
    /*createMenu();

    //ImageViewPane viewPane = new ImageViewPane(gridpane);

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(menuBar,gridpane);
    vbox.setBackground(new Background(fills));*/

    HBox hbox = new HBox(50);
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); // default TOP_LEFT

    VBox vbox1 = new VBox();
    //vbox1.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    vbox1.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid;"
            + "-fx-border-width: 1;"
            + "-fx-border-color: black");
    vbox1.setPrefSize(300, 300);
    vbox1.setFillWidth(true);

    VBox vbox2 = new VBox(10);
    vbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    vbox2.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid;"
            + "-fx-border-width: 1;"
            + "-fx-border-color: black");

    VBox vbox3 = new VBox(20);
    vbox3.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    vbox3.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid;"
            + "-fx-border-width: 1;"
            + "-fx-border-color: black");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Button bt = new Button("Button " + (i+1));
        Button bt2 = new Button("Button " + (i+1)); // unfortunately there´s no "clone" or "copy" method
        Button bt3 = new Button("Button " + (i+1));

        vbox1.getChildren().add(bt);
        vbox2.getChildren().add(bt2);
        vbox3.getChildren().add(bt3);
    }

    hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox1, vbox2, vbox3);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 350, 250); // the hbox is the root node
    //Scene scene = new Scene(vbox,600,600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Minesweeper");
    primaryStage.show();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

and i want the buttons in vbox1 to fill the remaining space (setfillwidth) but it doesn't work. Maybe iam not using it correctly.

Can someone explain this to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `maxWidth` property of the button to infinity to allow it taking all the available space.

```
bt.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21111031/2381172) for details.